# slide from right to left using slide toggle or animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide, slidetoggle

I have managed to get my code to work using `slideToggle` in the past, when I require the menu to slide from top to bottom. But now I need to slide my menu in from the right to the left. So I decided to adopt the `.animate` approach instead.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work fully:

```
    $(MENU_BUTTON).click(function() {
        $(MENU_ID).animate({ width:'245' }, 600);
    });
```

It does move from right to left, but only once and then it is stuck. Also, I would like it to slide in as well. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You have to set the width to 0 every time just before starting the animation if you don't want it to work only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first time, you animate it from left to right, next time, you animate it from right to right? If I understood you right, you want the menu to be hidden, and then when the button is pressed, the menu slides visible from left to right. Next time button is pressed, it slides back, from right to left. This is exactly what the code does, except for hiding the menu.

```
$(MENU_BUTTON).click(function() {
    var right = $(MENU_ID).hasClass('right');
    $(MENU_ID).toggleClass('right');
    // If you would like to hide/show it too.
    // Change the 0 to 0-$(MENU_ID).outerWidth();
    /* if (right) {
        setTimeout(function () {$(MENU_ID).hide();}, 600);
    } else $(MENU_ID).show(); */
    $(MENU_ID).animate({ width:(right?0:245) }, 600);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this kind of works. I may have confused you in question. It needs to always be right to left. So that it starts hidden and when the button is clicked slides from the right to the left and then back again when the button is clicked again

Comment: Maybe my english isn't perfect, but I still think it sounds like you want the menu to be hidden, and then when the button is pressed, the menu slides visible from left to right. Next time button is pressed, it slides back, from right to left. This is exactly what the code does, except for hiding the menu. Maybe you misunderstood me when I said "from left to right to left to..."?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/PFCq3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="upper">
        <li><a href="" title="">Dynamic item 1</a>

            <ul class="inner">
                <li> <a href="">Subitem 1 of 1</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="">Subitem 2 of 1</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="">Static item</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="">Dynamic item 2</a>

            <ul class="inner">
                <li><a href="">Subitem 1 of 2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.menu ul.upper li a {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu ul.inner {
    position: absolute;
    right: 160px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    right: 170px;
}
.menu ul.inner li a {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #3D6AA2;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.upper li').each(function() {
    $(this).find('ul.inner').css({top: $(this).offset().top})
});

$('.upper li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('ul.inner').stop(true, true).animate({
        width: "toggle"
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 250
    });
});
```